# Incrementing numbers until a specific number with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently doing a calendar using React and I'm trying to make a simple function so I don't have to write each time (00:00 - 23:00).

How can I increment every div with the class name `calendar-time` so it does something like this?

```
<div className="wrapper">
            <div className="calendar-time">
                00:00
            </div>
            <div className="calendar-time">
                01:00
            </div>
            <div className="calendar-time">
                02:00
            </div>
            <div className="calendar-time">
                03:00
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I tried:

```
render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        return(
            <div className="calendar-time">
                {i}:00
            </div>
        );
    }

    return(
        <div className="wrapper">

        </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{[...Array(24)].map((_, el) => (
    <div className="calendar-time" key={el}>
      {`${('0' + el).slice(-2)}:00`}
    </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    let hours = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        hours += `
            <div className="calendar-time">
                ${i}:00
            </div>
        `;
    }

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
           {hours}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure that your list of elements are rendered inside your wrapper element.

It is also a good idea to add a "key" attribute if you are mapping though a list and creating a list of elements as it helps react render stuff.

```
render() {
    // This is just an array of numbers [0,1,2...22,23]
    const hours = [...Array(23).keys()]

    return(
        <div className="wrapper">
           {hours.map((number) => (
                   <div key={`hour-${number}`} className="calendar-time">
                     {/* some string magic to make sure the the hour is always 2 digits long */}
                     {`${('0' + number).slice(-2)}:00`}
                   </div>
               );
           )}
        </div>
    );
}
```